# xcode custom overlay capture

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, cgrectmake

I am working on OCR recognition App and I want to give the user the option to manually select the area (during the camera selection) on which to perform the OCR. Now, the issue I face is that  I provide a rectangle on the camera screen by simply overriding the - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect method, However, despite there being a rectangle ,the camera tries to focus on the entire captured area rather than just within rectangle specified.

In other word, I do not want the entire picture to be send for processing but rather only the part of the captured image inside the rectangle. I have managed to provide a rectangle, However with no functionality. I do not want the entire screen area to be focused, but only the area under the rectangle.

I hope this makes sense since i have tried my best to explain it.
Thanks and let me know

Answer (score 1):

Stream the camera's image to a `UIScrollView` using an `AVCaptureOutput` then allow the user to pinch/pull/pan the camera into the proper place... now use `UIGraphics` Image `Context` to take a "screen-shot" of this area and send that `UIImage.CGImage` in for processing.

Comment: Hi Albert, Appreciate your response. What if I do not want to implement the pinch/pull feature, In the sense that I provide a fixed rectangle?  Thanks

Comment: That should be feasible as well. Use a `UIView` and size it the way you want. (You can even use a semi-transparent image as the view's background if you'd like). Make sure the view has a low `alpha` setting so the user can see whats behind it. Move the UIView by adjusting the `UIView.center` to a `CGPointMake` that has the x&y coordinates of a touch either using `touchesMoved` or a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`...

Comment: now when you implement your `UIGraphics` Image `Context` set the boundaries (`bounds`) to that of the `UIViews` coordinates and size (`bounds.size` or `view.frame.size`)... now set the view to `hidden` so it doesn't get in the way and take your "screenshot" when you're done set it back to visible by setting the `hidden` value to false.

Comment: (This time just place the camera's image in a `UIView` not a `UIScrollView` but still use the `AVCaptureOutput` method.)

Comment: Hi, Thanks again..I have another concern on the same front, Well as of now i am using the UIImagepickercontroller.                          UIImage *image = [info
                          objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
 I use this image and further process it for OCR, The prob is that if i use the AVCaptureOutput, how would I obtain the image for processing? I might sound a bit naive but since I am a new bie i would appreciate your help

Comment: Further, I am not using a UIView but feeding a fixed .png file for the rectangle

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22696/discussion-between-mikeazio-and-albert-renshaw)

Comment: I'd prefer to leave the discussion in the comments field to answer the same questions that future SO members may have when they look up this question.
`AVCaptureOutput` would be for live-stream video... If you are just using the `UIImagePickerController` so the user takes a photo then selects the area they needs you could use a .png and have them drag it over but it would be better to just use Apple's built in cropping tool designed for the `UIImagePickerController`

Comment: Set the tag `allowsImageEditing = YES;` for your `UIImagePickerController`, after the user selects their photo they will be taken to a screen where they crop the square out.

Like so: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QoASu.png